# Use opencv stitcher from python

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7

OpenCV can be used with the pythonbindings and it works quite well. However I was wondering (hoping really) whether it is possible to use [OpenCv's stitcher](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html) in python as well. I've tried several things but wasn't able to get it to work. If it is at all possible I probably need to do an extra import but I can't figure it out and google doesn't give me the answer either. Hope there's a opencv-python guru among you who can help me out.

Comment: Hey, I know it's probably a bit late for you, but I'm in position right now when I want to use the opencv Stitcher with python. I've figured out how to port other opencv classes "missing" from the opencv python API, and I've done it before. If I end up exponsing Stitcher to python, I'll have it by the end of today.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so, I figured it out finally. So far I've only ported the stitch method with two arguments, ask me if you have trouble exposing whatever else you might need.

The easiest way to build it is by compiling everything in a position-independent way (-fPIC option for gcc) into a dynamic library, whilst linking opencv_core and opencv_stitching libraries. You'll have to also add the include directory for whatever version of python you're building against, so it can find the correct Python.h header.

If you build correctly, you'll be able to use the compiled library the same way as you would use a python module.

Unfortunately, since they don't provide access to the constructor, I've had to settle for making a global instance of the thing. If there's another elegant way, I'm all ears (eyes).
This means whenever you call the .Stitcher() constructor it will return the same instance (there's a separate one that tries to use GPU during construction, use .Stitcher(True) for that).

Here's my pythonPort.h file:

```
/* 
 * File:   pythonPort.h
 * Author: algomorph
 *
 * Created on December 5, 2012, 10:18 AM
 */

#ifndef PYTHONPORT_H
#define PYTHONPORT_H

#define MODULESTR "mycv"


#include "Python.h"
#include "numpy/ndarrayobject.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp>
/*
//include your own custom extensions here
#include "savgol.h"
#include "filters.hpp"
*/
#include "pythonPortAux.h"

#endif
```

MODULESTR should be whatever you want to name your module. I've kept it the same as the name of the library it compiles.

You'll have to copy whatever opencv_to and opencv_from routines you need from the cv2.cpp file and put into something like my pythonPortAux.h. Mine has lots of routines from there, you can find it [at this link](http://algomorph.com/storage/pythonPortAux.h). MKTYPE2 macro is also there.

The rest is here in the pythonPort.cpp file below (I have other things there, this is just the Stitcher-relevant portion):

```
#include "pythonPort.h"

struct pycvex_Stitcher_t
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    Ptr<cv::Stitcher> v;
};

static PyTypeObject pycvex_Stitcher_Type =
{
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type)
    0,
    MODULESTR".Stitcher",
    sizeof(pycvex_Stitcher_t),
};

static void pycvex_Stitcher_dealloc(PyObject* self)
{
    //((pycvex_Stitcher_t*)self)->v.release();
    PyObject_Del(self);
}

static PyObject* pyopencv_from(const Ptr<cv::Stitcher>& r)
{
    pycvex_Stitcher_t *m = PyObject_NEW(pycvex_Stitcher_t, &pycvex_Stitcher_Type);
    new (&(m->v)) Ptr<cv::Stitcher>(); // init Ptr with placement new
    m->v = r;
    return (PyObject*)m;
}

static bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* src, Ptr<cv::Stitcher>& dst, const char* name="<unknown>")
{
    if( src == NULL || src == Py_None )
        return true;
    if(!PyObject_TypeCheck(src, &pycvex_Stitcher_Type))
    {
        failmsg("Expected cv::Stitcher for argument '%s'", name);
        return false;
    }
    dst = ((pycvex_Stitcher_t*)src)->v;
    return true;
}

static PyObject* pycvex_Stitcher_repr(PyObject* self)
{
    char str[1000];
    sprintf(str, "<Stitcher %p>", self);
    return PyString_FromString(str);
}

Stitcher gStitcher = cv::Stitcher::createDefault(false);
Stitcher gStitcherGPU = cv::Stitcher::createDefault(true);

static PyObject* pycvex_Stitcher_Stitcher(PyObject* , PyObject* args, PyObject* kw)
{
    PyErr_Clear();
    {
        pycvex_Stitcher_t* self = 0;
        bool try_use_gpu = false;

        const char* keywords[] = { "img", "pt1", "pt2","connectivity","leftToRight", NULL };
        if (PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kw, "|b:Stitcher",
                (char**) keywords, &try_use_gpu)){
            self = PyObject_NEW(pycvex_Stitcher_t, &pycvex_Stitcher_Type);
            if (self)
                ERRWRAP2(
                        if(try_use_gpu)
                            self->v = &gStitcherGPU;
                        else
                            self->v = &gStitcher;
                        );
            return (PyObject*) self;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
static PyGetSetDef pycvex_Stitcher_getseters[] =
{
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};

static PyObject* pycvex_Stitcher_stitch(PyObject* self, PyObject* args, PyObject* kw){
    if(!PyObject_TypeCheck(self, &pycvex_Stitcher_Type))
        return failmsgp("Incorrect type of self (must be 'Stitcher' or its derivative)");
    Stitcher* _self_ = ((pycvex_Stitcher_t*)self)->v;
    //Stitcher::Status status;
    int status;

    PyObject* pyobj_images = NULL;
    vector<Mat> images = vector<Mat>();
    Mat pano;

    const char* keywords[] = { "images", NULL };
    if( PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kw, "O:Stitcher.stitch", (char**)keywords, &pyobj_images) &&
        pyopencv_to(pyobj_images, images, ArgInfo("images", false)))
    {
        ERRWRAP2( status = (int)_self_->stitch(images, pano));
        return Py_BuildValue("(NN)", pyopencv_from(status), pyopencv_from(pano));
    }

    return NULL;
}

static PyMethodDef pycvex_Stitcher_methods[] =
{
    {"stitch", (PyCFunction)pycvex_Stitcher_stitch, METH_KEYWORDS, "stitch(image) -> status, pano"},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

static void pycvex_Stitcher_specials(void)
{
    pycvex_Stitcher_Type.tp_base = NULL;
    pycvex_Stitcher_Type.tp_dealloc = pycvex_Stitcher_dealloc;
    pycvex_Stitcher_Type.tp_repr = pycvex_Stitcher_repr;
    pycvex_Stitcher_Type.tp_getset = pycvex_Stitcher_getseters;
    pycvex_Stitcher_Type.tp_methods = pycvex_Stitcher_methods;
}


static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"Stitcher",(PyCFunction)pycvex_Stitcher_Stitcher, METH_KEYWORDS, "Stitcher([tryUseGpu=False]) -> <Stitcher object>"},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

extern "C"{
    #if defined WIN32 || defined _WIN32
    __declspec(dllexport)
    #endif
    void initcvex()
    {
      MKTYPE2(Stitcher);
      import_array();
      PyObject* m = Py_InitModule(MODULESTR, methods);
      PyObject* d = PyModule_GetDict(m);
      //PyDict_SetItemString(d, "__version__", PyString_FromString(CV_VERSION))
      opencv_error = PyErr_NewException((char*)MODULESTR".error", NULL, NULL);
      PyDict_SetItemString(d, "error", opencv_error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this could be useful, but I'm running into some trouble. Where is `filters.hpp` and `savgol.h`? I'm also getting errors regarding `python27_d.lib`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, you don't need those (filters.hpp and savgol.h). These were just for extentions I've added to opencv, for Berkley edge detection. I've commented them out from the code above.

Comment: As for python27_d.lib - this problem arises on Windows platforms when you're trying to compile anything referencing opencv in Debug mode. For a typical python windows installation, this library is not included. You can manually reconfigure the python bindings project of opencv to use python2.lib or try and reference the release build instead. If you're really intent on using it, consult this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315662/how-to-obtain-pre-built-debug-version-of-python-library-e-g-python27-d-dll

Comment: No, I decided to switch from python to c++ directly. It paid off, it was like an instant 5x speed boost without doing anything... of course now I have to deal with c++.

Comment: Oh... the 5x was completely subjective, I didn't actually measure anything, it is noticeably zippier though.

Comment: Well, I don't really know what your goals are here. Python bindings' only slow-down comes from converting the numpy arrays into Mat objects, other than that - the code it uses to do the operations is absolutely the same. The conversion slow-down is actually insignificant for anything I'm doing.

Comment: I'm also using opengl and doing a few other things, so I really can't say where the speedup came from.