# Error Compiling C++/Cuda extension with Pytorch Cuda c++ in MSVC using CMake

Tags: visual-c++, cuda, pytorch

I am trying to build a c++/cuda extension with Pytorch following the tutorial [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html), (with instructions how to use pytorch with c++ [here](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html#minimal-example)). My environment details are:

- Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 version 16.6.5
- Windows 10
- libtorch c++ debug 1.70 with cuda 11.0 installed from the pytorch website

I am using this cmake code where I set the include directory for python 3.6 and the library for python36.lib

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("DAConvolution")

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (DAConvolution "DAConvolution.cpp" "DAConvolution.h")

include_directories("C:/Users/James/Anaconda3/envs/masters/include")
   
target_link_libraries(DAConvolution "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}" "C:/Users/James/Anaconda3/envs/masters/libs/python36.lib")

if (MSVC)
  file(GLOB TORCH_DLLS "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/*.dll")
  add_custom_command(TARGET DAConvolution
                     POST_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                     ${TORCH_DLLS}
                     $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:DAConvolution>)
endif (MSVC)
```

I set the CMake command arguments to be -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\libtorch  (my path to libtorch debug mentioned above). I am building with the x64-debug option in MSVC version (as building with the x-64 Release option gives me a torch-NOTFOUND error).

```
The example DAConvolution.cpp file is:

#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#include <python.h>
#define _DEBUG
#else
#include <python.h>
#endif

#include <torch/extension.h>
```

Where I have undefined the _DEBUG flag so that the linker does not look for the python36_d.lib file (which I do not have).

I am getting a linking error:

[image]

Simply including torch.h works fine, but when I want to include the extension header thats when I get these problems, as it uses Pybind 11 I believe. Any insights much appreciated. I have tried to include all the info I can, but would be happy to give more information.

Comment: I'm doubtful that `add_executable` is what you want here. You're mixing instructions pertaining to building an extension to pytorch with instructions for building an application that links to pytorch C++ interface.  I think it's more likely you want `add_library`

Comment: Undefined main means you are trying to compile an executable out of code not designed to be compiled as an executable

Comment: @RobertCrovella ok this makes sense. It just seems that I want to be able to debug the pytorch extension in MSVC (ideally the .cu files as well). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RobertCrovella if you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: If you explain what you did to fix the issue or achieve your goal, I'm sure it will be more useful to future readers than my simple comment.  I haven't tested anything or tried to recreate what you are doing, so you are in a far better position here than I.  On SO, it's OK to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows and with Visual studio, you are better to work with the Visual Studio rather than the CMake.

Just create a simple Console Application, go to the project's Properties, change the `Configuration type` to `Dynamic Library (dll)`, Configure the include and Library directories, add the required enteries to your linker in `Linker>Input` (such as `torch.lib`, `torch_cpu.lib`, etc) and you are good to go click build, and if you have done everything correctly you'll get yourself a dll that you can use (e.g loading it using `torch.classes.load_library` from Python and use it.

The Python debug version is not shipped with Anaconda/ normal python distribution, but if you install the Microsoft Python distribution which I believe can be downloaded/installed from Visual Studio installer, its available.
Also starting from Python 3.8 I guess the debug binaries are also shipped.
In case they are not, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64725455/2736559).
For the cmake part you can follow something like the following. This is a butchered version taken from my own cmake that I made for my python extension some time ago.

Read it and change it based on your own requirements it should be straight forward :

```
# NOTE:‌
# TORCH_LIB_DIRS needs to be set. When calling cmake you can specify them like this:
# cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="somewhere/libtorch/share/cmake" -DTORCH_LIB_DIRS="/somewhere/lib" ..

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project(DAConvolution)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
# we are using the C++17, if you are not change this or remove it altogether
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

#define where your headers and libs are, specify for example where your DaConvolution.h resides!
include_directories( somewhere/Yourinclude_dir ${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(DAConvolution_SRC ./DAConvolution.cpp )

LINK_DIRECTORIES(${TORCH_LIB_DIRS})

add_library(
    DAConvolution
    SHARED
    ${DAConvolution_SRC}
  )

# if you use some custom libs, you previously built, specify its location here
# target_link_directories(DAConvolution PRIVATE somewhere/your_previously_built_stuff/libs)
target_link_libraries(DAConvolution ${TORCH_LIB_DIRS}/libc10.so)
target_link_libraries(DAConvolution ${TORCH_LIB_DIRS}/libtorch_cpu.so)

install(TARGETS DAConvolution LIBRARY DESTINATION lib )
```

Side note:
I made the cmake for Linux only, so under Windows, I always use Visual Studio (2019 to be exact), in the same way I explained earlier. its by far the best /easiest approach imho.  Suit yourself and choose either of them that best fits your problem.

Comment: Since I am trying ultimately to code/debug a c++ pytorch extension, in particular a custom function (with custom forward and backwards implementations ultimately drawing from CUDA api calls in c++), I am curious why a torchsript dll is what I should be building? Thank you very much for the help, I will study your answer in the next coming days.

Comment: as you already know basically when it comes to building extensions for torch, you either need to go torchscript/torch extension, or pybind11. I myself found the torchscript/extension scenario easier, as you only have to create a class and expose it and everything is built as a dll which in VS is very easy to do. For Pybind11, I had to use a `setup.py` and build the very same extension, which are quit similar(torchextension is basically a pybind11 lookalike). However the setup part was/is kind of a headache for me.

Comment: Also have a look [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/torch_script_custom_ops.html)  and [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/torch_script_custom_classes.html).

Comment: @Rika I've run into this issue. Any references on the pybind11-based approach, as opposed to the Torchscript extension?